# MS Excel - Data Validation - Multiple conditions(List,Custom) - on a single cell

Tags: excel, list, validation, excel-formula, dropdown

On a single cell A3 , I need to apply 2 different options via Data Validation. How can it be done?
First one is it should list a dropdown of values. (List : Sheet2!$A$1:$A$7)
Second one is it should validate a condition whether previous cell is filled or not ( custom : LEN(A2)<>0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the active cell within the worksheet is `A3`, go to *Name Manager* and define *MyVal* as:

`=IF(LEN(A2)<>0,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$7,Sheet2!$B$1)`

where `Sheet2!$B$1` should be left deliberately blank.

The Data Validation for cell `A3` can then be set to the *List* option with the following formula:

`=MyVal`

and *Ignore blank* unchecked.

If cell `A2` does not contain a value, the only permitted entry in cell `A3` will be a blank; otherwise the dropdown list appears.

Comment: This works on A3, but I have to apply it for 100 rows ( A2 to A101 ). for A4 it should validate the length of A3 and so on.

Comment: The validation can simply be copied to other cells as required. Hence my use of a mix of relative and absolute references.